# PLSQL Insert into with subquery and returning clause

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, insert, return-value

I can't figure out the correct syntax for the following pseudo-sql:

```
INSERT INTO some_table
           (column1,
            column2)
     SELECT col1_value, 
            col2_value 
       FROM other_table
      WHERE ...       
  RETURNING id
       INTO local_var;
```

I would like to insert something with the values of a subquery.
After inserting I need the new generated id.

Heres what oracle doc says:

[Insert Statement](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/insert_statement.htm#sthref2803)

[Returning Into](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/returninginto_clause.htm)

OK i think it is not possible only with the values clause...
Is there an alternative?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You cannot use the RETURNING BULK COLLECT from an INSERT. 
This methodology can work with updates and deletes howeveer:

```
create table test2(aa number)
/
insert into test2(aa)
      select level
        from dual
        connect by level<100
/        

set serveroutput on
declare 
     TYPE t_Numbers IS TABLE OF test2.aa%TYPE
        INDEX BY BINARY_INTEGER;
      v_Numbers t_Numbers;
      v_count number;
begin


update test2
  set aa = aa+1
returning aa bulk collect into v_Numbers;

    for v_count in 1..v_Numbers.count loop
        dbms_output.put_line('v_Numbers := ' || v_Numbers(v_count));
    end loop;

end;
```

You can get it to work with a few extra steps (doing a FORALL INSERT utilizing TREAT)
as described in this article:

[returning with insert..select](http://www.oracle-developer.net/display.php?id=413)

T

to utilize the example they create and apply it to test2 test table

```
 CREATE or replace TYPE ot AS OBJECT
    ( aa number);
/


CREATE TYPE ntt AS TABLE OF ot;
/

set serveroutput on
 DECLARE

       nt_passed_in ntt;
       nt_to_return ntt;

       FUNCTION pretend_parameter RETURN ntt IS
          nt ntt;
       BEGIN
          SELECT ot(level) BULK COLLECT INTO nt
         FROM   dual
         CONNECT BY level <= 5;
         RETURN nt;
      END pretend_parameter;

   BEGIN

      nt_passed_in := pretend_parameter();

      FORALL i IN 1 .. nt_passed_in.COUNT
         INSERT INTO test2(aa)
         VALUES
         ( TREAT(nt_passed_in(i) AS ot).aa
         )
         RETURNING ot(aa)
         BULK COLLECT INTO nt_to_return;

      FOR i IN 1 .. nt_to_return.COUNT LOOP
         DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(
            'Sequence value = [' || TO_CHAR(nt_to_return(i).aa) || ']'
            );
      END LOOP;

   END;
   /
```

Comment: That's cool! The only problem left for me is to declare the object types. It is not possible to declare object types in a package...

Answer (score 21):

Unfortunately that's not possible.  RETURNING is only available for INSERT...VALUES statements.  See [this Oracle forum thread](http://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=449776&start=0&tstart=0) for a discussion of this subject.

Answer (score 5):

You can't, BUT at least in Oracle 19c, you can specify a `SELECT` subquery inside the `VALUES` clause and so use `RETURNING`! This can be a good workaround, even if you may have to repeat the `WHERE` clause for every field:

```
INSERT INTO some_table
           (column1,
            column2)
     VALUES((SELECT col1_value FROM other_table WHERE ...),
            (SELECT col2_value FROM other_table WHERE ...))
  RETURNING id
       INTO local_var;
```

Answer (score -1):

Because the insert is based on a select, Oracle is assuming that you are permitting a multiple-row insert with that syntax. In that case, look at the multiple row version of the returning clause document as it demonstrates that you need to use BULK COLLECT to retrieve the value from all inserted rows into a collection of results.

After all, if your insert query creates two rows - which returned value would it put into an single variable?

**EDIT - Turns out this doesn't work as I had thought.... darn it!**

Comment: I tried that but i get an ORA 009333. SQL command not properly ended after the where. collection type is a good idea.

Comment: As Tony said in his answer, BULK COLLECT doesn't work with INSERT -- at least in 10g and earlier.  I'm not clear on whether this has changed in 11g.

Comment: yes, I thought this worked but it seems that it does not. Sorry for the bad advice.

Answer (score -3):

This isn't as easy as you may think, and certainly not as easy as it is using MySQL. Oracle doesn't keep track of the last inserts, in a way that you can ping back the result.

You will need to work out some other way of doing this, you can do it using ROWID - but this has its pitfalls.

This link discussed the issue: http://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=352627

Comment: That's not really relevant to the question asked -- it wasn't about identifying the last row inserted by any session, it was about returning a set of values from a specific INSERT statement.