# Move rows between tables using single statement in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

Due to stupid legacy system limitations I am trying to write the following query using one single statement:

```
insert into dbo.mytable_archive 
  select * 
    from dbo.mytable 
   where date < trunc(sysdate) - 14;

delete from dbo.mytable 
 where date < trunc(sysdate) - 14;
```

Using the power of Google I find that this seems possible in many other databases using the `RETURNING` clause i Postgres or `OUTPUT` clause in SQLServer but I am unable to find an equivalent solution for Oracle (V12).

Any idea for a workaround?

Comment: No way to do this with a single statement in Oracle. Unless we have a magician here. I would like to be wrong because that would be very handy. And btw the same question was already asked on [DBA Stack](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/107975/cut-records-from-one-table-into-another-in-one-oracle-sql-statement)

Comment: If I understand well, you need a returning in the first statement, and then want to use the result of the first query in the second one; if so, have a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5325033/plsql-insert-into-with-subquery-and-returning-clause-oracle).

Comment: isnt this the perfect case for a trigger? everytime you delete something, save it into the archive table?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In case your statement runs around midnight and may take longer than 1 second you should better do this:

```
create or replace procedure move_to_arch as
   theDate DATE := trunc(sysdate) - 14;
begin
insert into dbo.mytable_archive 
  select * 
    from dbo.mytable 
   where date < theDate ;

delete from dbo.mytable 
 where date < theDate ;
commit;
end;
/
```

Comment: Isn't it exacly the same answer as mine?

Comment: No, if you run your procedure at 23:59:00 and INSERT takes longer than 1 Minute then DELETE will delete different data because `trunc(sysdate) - 14` returns different value.

Comment: OK, you're right I should set date on begining of procedure not dinamically. Thanks.

Comment: Is it possible for two parallel executions of `move_to_arch` to cause rows to end up double-inserted into the archive table? The reasoning being that the subselect in the `insert` does not take any locks, so both racing transactions can see the same set of rows in the subselect.

Comment: Yes, it would be possible to have data double-inserted into mytable_archive. Would this be a problem? One possible solution could be a partitioned table (one partition per day) where you run "exchange partition".

Comment: I believe another solution would be to add `lock table dbo.mytable in share row exclusive mode;` prior to the insert.

Answer (score 2):

What are your limitations? If you want to call single statement you can:

```
create or replace procedure move_to_arch as
begin
insert into dbo.mytable_archive 
  select * 
    from dbo.mytable 
   where date < trunc(sysdate) - 14;

delete from dbo.mytable 
 where date < trunc(sysdate) - 14;
commit;
end;
/
```

And then with one statement:

```
exec move_to_arch();
```

Comment: @NicholasKrasnov yes you're right. I'll edit answer now

Answer (score 0):

You still need 2 statements, one for `insert` and one for `delete`. `Returning` will just help you saving id for exemple.
Oracle provides `returning into` keyworks

Comment: Not sure about Postgres, but MS SQL's `OUTPUT` can be used for that - you can do `DELETE`, output the deleted rows through `OUTPUT` as a resultset and insert that resultset using `INSERT`.

Answer (score 0):

Use in-memory table to cache the result of the delete statement. This avoids reading the records two times from the disk.

```
create or replace procedure move_to_arch as
  TYPE mytableType IS table OF dbo.mytable%ROWTYPE;
  t mytableType;
begin
  delete from dbo.mytable 
  where date < trunc(sysdate) - 14
  RETURNING col1,col2 BULK COLLECT INTO t;

  FORALL J IN t.FIRST..t.LAST
    INSERT INTO dbo.mytable_archive VALUES t(J);
end;
/
```