# PL Sql BULK COLLECT SQL command not property ended

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, bulk-collect

I am trying to use BULK COLLECT INTO but I get an ORA-00933 SQL command not properly ended. I'm looked at my syntax but not sure what I am doing wrong. Am I doing something wrong?

The issue seems to be with the RETURNING clause. If I remove the returning clause, it compiles just fine

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE CIMS.QC_PALLET_HOLD_BY_HOUR_A_REL( QC_HOLD_ID_IN IN INTEGER, HOUR_STR IN VARCHAR2, DAY_CODE IN VARCHAR2, TOP_CODE_IN IN VARCHAR2, QC_RLS_DISPOSITION_ID_IN INTEGER, SUCC_PALS_OUT OUT VARCHAR2)
IS
    l_count binary_integer;
    l_array dbms_utility.lname_array;
    curr_prod_hour varchar2(1);     
    TYPE success_hours is TABLE of pallet_hold.pallet_no%type;
    TYPE t_pallet_ids is TABLE of pallet_hold.pallet_hold_id%type;

BEGIN

    dbms_utility.comma_to_table(
        list => regexp_replace(HOUR_STR, '(^|,)','\1x'),
        tablen => l_count,
        tab => l_array
    );

        BEGIN
            forall i in l_array.FIRST .. l_array.last
            INSERT INTO PALLET_HOLD(PALLET_NO, TOP_CODE, BOTTOM_CODE, QC_HOLD_ID)
            SELECT V.PALLET_NO, V.TOP_CODE, V.BOTTOM_CODE, QC_HOLD_ID_IN
            FROM PALLET_MASTER_INQ_VIEW V
            WHERE PROD_HOUR = substr(l_array(i),2) AND SUBSTR(BOTTOM_CODE,0,5) = DAY_CODE AND TOP_CODE = TOP_CODE_IN
            AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM PALLET_HOLD WHERE QC_HOLD_ID = QC_HOLD_ID_IN AND PALLET_NO = V.PALLET_NO)
            RETURNING PALLET_HOLD_ID bulk collect INTO t_pallet_ids;

        EXCEPTION
            WHEN OTHERS THEN
                NULL;
        END;              

    COMMIT;

    EXCEPTION
        WHEN OTHERS THEN 
         RAISE; --raise_application_error(-20333, 'Error QC_PALLET_HOLD_BY_HOUR');

END;
/
```

Comment: Exception when others then null:  love it!!!. Can you make an output there of the exception fired, just to check if something went wrong?

Comment: Ya sorry. I can add an output, but the problem is I'm unable to even compile this procedure, so I'm unable to run it

Comment: "RETURNING PALLET_HOLD_ID bulk collect INTO t_pallet_ids" ..... this seems like an unwanted line after a INSERT INTO ..... SELECT .... .Clause

Comment: I am attemping to get the pallet_hold_id column values that were generated by a sequence trigger.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PLSQL Insert into with subquery and returning clause (Oracle)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5325033/plsql-insert-into-with-subquery-and-returning-clause-oracle)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you can't use the returning statement the way you're attempting to. The answer to this question will give you options on how to accomplish your task.

[PLSQL Insert into with subquery and returning clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5325033/plsql-insert-into-with-subquery-and-returning-clause-oracle)